# Using re.sub to replace numeric part of string, with arithmetic manipulation of that number in Python?

Tags: python, regex, arithmetic-expressions, backreference

Let's say I have the string `testing-1-6-180` - here I'd want to capture the second digit (whatever it is), here it being "6", and then I want to add 5 to its numeric value (so 6), and then output the string - so in this case, the result should be `testing-1-11-180`.

This is what I tried so far:

```py
import re

mytext = "testing-1-6-180"
pat_a = re.compile(r'testing-1-(\d+)')
result = pat_a.sub( "testing-1-{}".format( int('\1')+5 ), mytext )
```

... unfortunately, this fails with:

```
$ python3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    result = pat_a.sub( "testing-1-{}".format( int('\1')+5 ), mytext )
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x01'
```

So, how could I get the captured backreference, so I can convert it to int, do some arithmetic, and then use the result to replace the matching substring?

---

Would have been nice to be able to post an answer, as it is not exactly trivial to figure out how to apply the answers there to this problem here, but noone cares anyways, so I'll post the answer as an edit:

```py
import re

mytext = "testing-1-6-180"
pat_a = re.compile(r'testing-1-(\d+)')

def numrepl(matchobj):
  return "testing-1-{}".format( int(matchobj.group(1))+5 )

result = pat_a.sub( numrepl, mytext )
print(result)
```

and the result is `testing-1-11-180`.

Comment: Your question is reopened; feel free to roll ba5k your edit and post an answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a lambda in replacement:

```
>>> mytext = "testing-1-6-180"
>>> s = re.sub(r'^(\D*\d+\D+)(\d+)', lambda m: m.group(1) + str(int(m.group(2)) + 5), mytext)
>>> print (s)
'testing-1-11-180'
```